# Where can I find repository source for 2.3.19 release?

Tags: freemarker

I need to patch the 2.3.19 release of FreeMarker. I would like to possibly contribute back as well, so I am looking for the repository source. I see that project is now maintained in GitHub, and the active branch seems to be 2.3-gae. But I believe this is the active development branch for 2.3.20, which would be fine for the contribution but we need 2.3.19 to release with.

Does anyone know where I can find this? I did not see any tags or anything to indicate the source for that release version.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: https://sourceforge.net/p/freemarker/code/HEAD/tree/tags/2.3.19/

BTW, the source code is also include in the distribution.